# Вложенные интеракторы или нет

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Есть 2 интерактора `AuthInteractor` и `UserInteractor`
После авторизации нужно указать(задать) текущего пользователя через `UserInteractor`(потому что приложение мультиаккаунтное, и можно залогинится с разных акк, после логина автоматически должен становится активным пользователем).

Сейчас, `AuthViewModel` отправляет команду авторизации в `AuthInteractor`, после получения авторизации(там есть информация об ID пользователя) `AuthViewModel` отправляет команду установки текущего пользователя в `UserInteractor`.
Такое взаимодействие правильное? Или создать третий интерактор (`SuperAuthInteractor`) в котором есть `AuthInteractor` и `UserInteractor` и все делать внутри `SuperAuthInteractor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Архитектура - это штука, которая позволяет быстрее и удобнее разрабатывать. Прикиньте на глаз, какую выгоду Вам может принести переделка логики интеракторов, и сколько такая переделка займет времени и сил. Если считаете, что оно того стоит, то делайте, иначе - оставляйте как есть.

Конкретно в случае с авторизацией, я, например, никаких выгод не вижу. Но если в любом случае планируете крупные работы с авторизацией (ее полный рефакторинг, например), то лучше создать `SuperAuthInteractor`. Однообразие стиля кода - это тоже плюс.